# Bootstrap Vertical Scrollable Table

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my Angular program, I want to have a scrollable table. I've tried using the css that I've seen on here but it doesn't work at all like the ones that I see. I've made a bootply here: https://www.bootply.com/el0aE4hBfj

and whenever I add the `.css` that I've seen to make it scrollable:

```css
.table-fixed{
  width: 100%;

}

.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%
}

.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}

.table-fixed tbody td, .table-fixed thead > tr > th {
  float: left;
  border-bottom-width: 0;
}
```

it, completely destroys it.

How can I get my table to be scrollable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding:

```css
tbody {
  display: block;
  height: 195px;
  overflow: auto;
}

thead, tbody tr {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

thead {
  width: calc( 100% - 1em )
}
```

instead of what I had in my OP

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to wrap your tables into a div and set the following styles:

```
.t-wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

with the following HTML

```
<div class="t-wrapper">
    <table>
        // Your table...
    </table>
</div>
```

This will make the tables scrollable, if they don't fit inside their container.

Comment: this would probably work if I wanted my table to be horizontally scrollable, but I want it to scroll vertically with the header and footer fixed at the top & bottom with only the body being scrollable